# Do copper blocks oxidize indoors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Does Minecraft 1.17.1 do any check to see if a copper block is sheltered before oxidizing it?

If so, what are the requirements for the shelter? Does it have to be enclosed, or just have a roof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer, yes, there are requirements for oxidation of copper blocks, and yes, they do oxidize indoors. It won't matter if you enclose it, or put a roof over it. The only way to *prevent* oxidation, is to add wax to the block.

---

To elaborate on this by summarizing [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Copper), copper has four stages of oxidation, including its initial state. Oxidation relies on random ticks and is unaffected by things like weather:

> Rain or water does not accelerate oxidation, and covering copper blocks with other blocks does not prevent oxidation.

It is described, that in [minecraft-java-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition), when a random tick is given, there is a ~5.69% chance that a copper block will enter it's pre-oxidation state:

> In Java Edition, when a random tick is given, a copper block has a 64⁄1125 chance to enter a state called pre-oxidation. This means a copper block enters pre-oxidation after approximately 20 minutes.

<sub>***Note**: I'm unsure if this works the same in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).*</sub>

During pre-oxidation, copper blocks search nearby, unwaxed, copper blocks to determine if pre-oxidation should end:

> In pre-oxidation, the copper block searches its nearby unwaxed copper blocks for a distance of 4 blocks Manhattan distance. If there is any copper block that has a lower oxidation level, then the pre-oxidation ends, meaning that this copper block does not weather.

The wiki also defines the probability of oxidation quite clearly:

> Let ***a*** be the number of all nearby unwaxed copper blocks, and ***b*** be the number of nearby unwaxed copper blocks that have a higher oxidation level. We derive the value of ***c*** from this equation:
>
> ```
> c = b + 1⁄a + 1
> ```
>
> We also let the modifying factor ***m*** be *0.75* if the copper block has no oxidation level, or *1* if the copper block is exposed or weathered. Then the oxidation probability is ***mc<sup>2</sup>***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, only way to stop it from oxidizing is using honeycomb to wax it.

Comment: Welcome to Arcade by the way, if you want, here's a [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)